# How to declare and use extended control in master page

Tags: 2010, development

Regarding my question, I have an OOTB control called ProjectProperty, which i can call in sharepoint like that:

```
<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />
```

I want to extend this control.
So i created a class which derives from this control:

```
 public class SiteProperty : ProjectProperty
```

And i added some functionality in this class.

My question now is, how can I use this extended customcontrol in the MasterPage.
Where or how do I say that ok this is CustomControl and it should be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register your solution/project assembly in the masterpage and/or pagelayouts like so:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="<Prefix>" Namespace="<NameSpace>" Assembly="<Assembly>" %>
```

Example:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="DandroidControl" Namespace="Dandroid.SharePoint.Controls" Assembly="Dandroid.SharePoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31ffcf8d61f9c2fb" %>
```